# Find the intersection between two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

We consider these vectors in $\mathbb R^4$:
\begin{gather*}
u_1=(1,1,2,1)^T,\quad u_2=(1,-1,0,-1)^T,\\
v_1=(1,9,10,9)^T,\quad u_2=(1,7,8,7)^T
\end{gather*}
And we have that $B=\{u_1,u_2\}$ and $C=\{v_1,v_2\}$
both are bases for the same subspace (plane) $U\subset\mathbb R^4$

Now we consider the xy-plane in $\mathbb R^4$ with the subspace $$V=\{(x_1,x_2,0,0) \in\mathbb R^4\mid x_1,x_2 \in\mathbb R\}.$$

Now I have to find the intersection $U \cap V$ between these two planes.
I find it a bit abstract, and can't see how to find this. It's linear algebra so probably just some equations systems I have to solve. Can anyone help me with some hints?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^4$ a "plane" is a 3-dimensional entity.

Comment: @Cesareo That's a question of terminology. It is not unusual to refer to $2$-dimensional real subspaces as "planes" generally and use the term "hyperplane" for subspaces of codimension $1$.

Comment: My point is that you can't expect to have a "line" as the intersection of two such "planes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point $x\in U\cap V$ can be written as
$$
x = t\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}+s\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}
$$
since it is in $U$ and has $x_3=x_4=0$ since it is in $V$. Hence
$$
t\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}+s\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is a system of four linear equations in four variables.

Indeed the third row $t\cdot 2 + s\cdot 0 = 0$ gives you $t=0$ immediately and then the fourth row implies $s=0$ as well. Hence, the only point in $U\cap V$ is given by $t=0$, $s=0$ which yields $x=(0,0,0,0)^T$.

We conclude that $U\cap V=0=\{(0,0,0,0)^T\}$.